# How can I press two keys at once using WebdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, selenium, key, webdriver-io

I'm attempting to write code using WebdriverIO that presses down the shift and tab keys at once.

I am able to press each individual key using `browser.keys("\uE004");` and `browser.keys("\uE008");` however these actions are not performed simultaneously.

I also tried passing in an array as `browser.keys(["\uE004", "\uE008"]);` but this also presses one key at a time.  Help!  How can I press both keys at once?

Comment: Did you try pushing the SHIFT first? Make it the leftmost character in the array of chars?

Comment: Thanks, I did try configuring the code so that it presses SHIFT first, however it still executes each key in order (not simultaneously).  Any other ideas?

Comment: Any news on this? I am trying to perform STRG + V paste.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and was resolved after referring to https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1344.

The modifiers (Control, Shift, Alt) are not released by default. You have to pass 'NULL' to release the modifier key.

E.g.: `browser.keys(['Control', 'r', 'NULL'])`

So in your array, include NULL as the third element. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: This solution does not work for me, Control and v are not pressed at the same time. I am on WDIO5

Comment: @Gobliins: Can you share the snippet of the code that you tried?

Comment: Exactly the same, but it seems maybe the issue is, that the clipboard can not contain graphics.... so it was empty